# Select specific div created using for loop in a function which is inside the for loop

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show thumbnail of selected files with a multiple image upload input field. Here is how it should work -

1. User selects multiple pictures(example 5 pictures)
2. For each file the code should create a div(as thumbnail)
3. As pictures filesize is huge, it might take some time for the browser to convert to blob. So I am showing loading gif for each file inside the thumbnail div. Thumbnail div class name is the picture name(so that I can identify later)
4. Pictures start converting to blob using `create_blob(file, callback)` function
5. Once each picture is converted to blob, it should replace the specific loading gif with the blob code

My Problem right now:
It creates the same amount of divs as selected pictures amount. Shows loading.gif properly. However, only the last div keeps getting updated everytime a picture has been converted. I want to update specific div for the specific image. I understand the variable gets updated during the loop as it's asynchronous before I get the result. I want to keep this asynchronous but I also want to achieve step 5

Here is my code so far -

```
<input type="file" multiple id="add-file" accept="image/*">
<div id="output">
</div>
<script>
(function ($) {
$('#add-file').change(function() {
var files = this.files;
for (var i = 0, file; file = files[i]; i++) {
selected_div = file.name.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, "").replace(/[_\s]/g, "-");
$( "#output" ).append( '<div class="section '+selected_div+'"><input type="hidden" class="blob-holder" name="gallery[]" /><img src="loading.gif" 
class="thumb" /></div>' );
create_blob(file, function(blob_string) {
$( "."+selected_div ).find( "img" ).attr('src', blob_string);
$( "."+selected_div ).find( "input" ).val(blob_string);
});
}
});
function create_blob(file, callback) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function() { callback(reader.result) };
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/b0xed/mfq54h9r/1/

How can I achieve step 5 and still keep this asynchronous?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because you are using `selected_div` from parent function which is getting updated immediately and ended up with the last div you should pass it as a parameter as well.

```
function create_blob(file, divSelector, callback) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function() { callback(reader.result, divSelector) };
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

and you need to call it as below;

```
create_blob(file, selected_div, function(blob_string, divSelector) {
   $( "."+divSelector).find( "img" ).attr('src', blob_string);
   $( "."+divSelector).find( "input" ).val(blob_string);
});
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. It didn't come to my mind, to pass the selector to the `create_blob()` function.